# I am getting error while using "cabal build all" cmd

Tags: plutus, haskell, cabal, plutus-starter

I am new to plutus. I am trying to learn plutus for which I am using "plutus-starter" code to begin. while using "cabal build" i am getting following error:

```
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
[__0] trying: Win32-network-0.1.0.0 (user goal)
[__1] trying: base-4.16.4.0/installed-4.16.4.0 (dependency of Win32-network)
[__2] next goal: byron-spec-chain (user goal)
[__2] rejecting: byron-spec-chain-0.1.0.0 (conflict:
base==4.16.4.0/installed-4.16.4.0, byron-spec-chain => base>=4.12 && <4.15)
[__2] fail (backjumping, conflict set: base, byron-spec-chain)
After searching the rest of the dependency tree exhaustively, these were the
goals I've had most trouble fulfilling: base, byron-spec-chain, Win32-network
```

How can I solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong version of GHC which supplies the `base` library.

According to https://www.snoyman.com/base/ `base` version `4.16.*` is supplied by `ghc-9.2.*` .

From the bounds required on `base` (`base>=4.12 && <4.15`) I would suspect you should be using `ghc-8.10.7`.

Comment: I think it solved my problem. Thank you very much.